# node-gyp could not open .lib modules on windows

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I have written a code to call some functions from openldap C library for Windows. The program have compiled, but when I call a function I get the next error text:

```
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\cghitea\Desktop\nodeLdapClient\build\Release\binding.node
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:434:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cghitea\Desktop\nodeLdapClient\test.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

I have tried to run the same code on Linux and it worked. It seems to me that node-gyp could not open the .lib files from C library.

Here is my code from binding.gyp

```
{
  #'variables': {
    #  
   # },
  'targets': [
    {
      'target_name': 'binding',
      'defines': [ 'V8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' ],
      'include_dirs' : [
        "../nodeLdapClient/node_modules/nan",
        "../nodeLdapClient/openldapsdk/inc",
        "../nodeLdapClient/openldapsdk/bin",
        "../nodeLdapClient/openldapsdk/lib",
        ],
      'sources': [ 'binding.cc' ],
      'dll_files': [
        '../openldapsdk/bin/libeay32.dll',
        '../openldapsdk/bin/ldapssl.dll',
        '../openldapsdk/bin/liblber.dll', 
        '../openldapsdk/bin/libldap.dll', 
        '../openldapsdk/bin/libldap_r.dll',
        '../openldapsdk/bin/liblunicode.dll',
        '../openldapsdk/bin/liblutil.dll',
        '../openldapsdk/bin/nldapextd.dll',
        '../openldapsdk/bin/ssleay32.dll'
      ],
      'libraries': [
        '../openldapsdk/lib/ldap_ssl.lib',
        '../openldapsdk/lib/libeay32.lib',
        '../openldapsdk/lib/liblber.lib', 
        '../openldapsdk/lib/libldap.lib', 
        '../openldapsdk/lib/libldap_r.lib',
        '../openldapsdk/lib/liblunicode.lib',
        '../openldapsdk/lib/liblutil.lib',
        '../openldapsdk/lib/nldapextd.lib',
        '../openldapsdk/lib/ssleay32.lib'
        ],
      'cflags!': ['-fno-exceptions'],
      'cflags': ['-std=c++11'],
      'cflags_cc': ['-fno-exceptions'],
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Why on Windows the node-gyp compile the C/C++ files without error and create the object .node and the script can not open/find the module?

Comment: I don't know, or how would I usually say: "Nu is curios".